# Radio Groups with clickable label

Tags: html, forms, webforms

From what I have gathered, in order to make a label of a radio button clickable, you must assign the same "name" attribute value to both elements.

The problem I am having is when you have more than one radio button, say a "yes or no" type selection. In order to make it to where if you click one, the other disables is that both radio buttons "name" attribute has to be the same value.

Is it possible to do both?

```
<label for="no">No</label> 
<input type="radio" name="no" value="no" />

<label for="yes">Yes</label> 
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes" />
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`id` (*not name*) attribute should be referred by label's [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes) attribute. It should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zzsSw/

```
<label for="no">No</label> 
<input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="no" value="no" />

<label for="yes">Yes</label> 
<input type="radio" name="mygroup" id="yes" value="yes" />
```

Comment: Makes sense. Now I can just assign the correct name for both elements? http://jsfiddle.net/zzsSw/1/

Answer (score 38):

You can also write labels without IDs:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="mygroup" />
  My clickable caption
</label>
```

or checkbox

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mygroup[]" />
  My clickable caption
</label>
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Comment: I disagree that it's better. If you have to support old IE, elements with names may be found by `document.getElementById`, which will search both IDs and names. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx under Remarks.

If IE7 or below is still a target for you (even if you're support IE10 but in IE7 standards mode etc), you should really be putting names AND IDs on these elements.

Comment: I wrote a lot of HTML like this and now regret doing so. I can't see any obvious way to  programmatically relocate the caption for e.g. a table layout.