# Making radio button text clickable without adding any HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know if you have radio buttons and you want to make the text clickable, you can wrap the button in a label HTML tag as described here [How do you make the radio button text to be clickable too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412204/how-do-you-make-the-radio-button-text-to-be-clickable-too).

But can this be done without adding any extra HTML (through Javascript or jQuery only)?

What I do have in my particular case is the group of radio buttons is inside a div and each radio and its text has a span (but they all have the same name). Here is an example..

```
Which team will win the world series in 2015?
   <div id="teams"><span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="11">&nbsp; Cardinals</span> 
 <span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="12">&nbsp; Royals</span> 
 <span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="13">&nbsp; Dodgers</span> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without extra HTML, using jQuery ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shub01/u76hk144/)):

```js
$('span.team').css('cursor', 'default').click(function(e) {
  var cur = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked')
  $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', !cur); //true turns false and vice versa
});

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); //otherwise the actual radio buttons won't work properly
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Which team will win the world series in 2015?
<div id="teams">
  <span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="11">&nbsp; Cardinals</span> 
  <span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="12">&nbsp; Royals</span> 
  <span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="13">&nbsp; Dodgers</span> 
</div>
```

This will change the cursor to match the style of a `label` elements and also *unselect* the currently selected radio button on another click.

---

However, you could just change your `span`'s to `label`'s - they will work in exactly the same way.

Comment: add stopPropagation to the click of radio buttons. and then you will get a 1 up :)

Comment: You have to put stopPropagation on click of radio buttons not the spans containing them

Comment: @TejasvaDhyani whoops! The effect is still *almost* the same - it's just that the click on radio button won't work! Sorry! Updated! :)

Comment: Thats fine, atleast for now. Try making it fool proof. Consider a case where the user clicks on the radio button again, but somehow he is not able to reverse its status.(the default radio button behavior do not support unchecking the radio). You can implement this functionality as well if you want. cheers !

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to replace the `span` elements with `label` elements by code.
But only do this if the `span` elements are not used elsewhere in the JavaScript code.

```
$('span.team').each(function() {
    $('<label>').addClass('team').html($(this).html()).insertAfter($(this);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't write new html, you can with jquery:

```
 // make click in anywhere of the span
 $('span.team').on('click', function() {
      var radio = $(this).find('input[type=radio]'); // the input
      if(radio.prop('checked')) {
          radio.prop('checked', false); // checking false
      } else {
          radio.prop('checked', true); //checking true
      } 
 });
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is when the radio button is clicked, then also the span's click will trigger and thus again working on the same radio button. In that case, you must provide with stopPropagation in case of click on radio buttons. However, I think that you can get away with the radio buttons but consider if they were checkboxes.

Comment: Yes , this code is an aproximation. Obviously there are lots of tests to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can force selection on click:

```js
$(function() {
  $('span.team').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).children('input[name=team]').prop('checked', true); // mark this
  });
});
```

```css
span.team {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Which team will win the world series in 2015?
<div id="teams"><span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="11">&nbsp; Cardinals</span> 
  <span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="12">&nbsp; Royals</span> 
  <span class="team"><input type="radio" name="team" value="13">&nbsp; Dodgers</span> 
</div>
```